# a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION transformServers(data jsonb)
RETURNS SETOF record  as $$                        
DECLARE                                            
r record;                                          

BEGIN                                              
for r in select.serversSet.id,serversSet.hostname from jsonb_to_recordset(data->'data') AS           
 serversSet (                                       
 id bigint,                                         
 hostname text,                                                                                                                                  
) loop                                             
return next r;                                     
end loop;                                          
return;  
 END;
 $$ language plpgsql;
```

I run the above code, got an error saying " a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"

Comment: problem solved! Happy. actually the problem is in another function which I call transformServers(json). each time we call a function which returns setof record, we need to specify the columns, so when we call transformServers(json)., like      `select * from transformServers(json).as f(id bigint, hostname text) ` I did `select * from transformServers(json)` before

Answer (score 7):

Problem solved! Actually the problem is in another function, where I call `transformServers(json)`.

Each time we call a function which `returns setof record`, we need to specify the columns, so when we call `transformServers(json)` we have to do it as

```
 select * from transformServers(json) as f(id bigint, hostname text)
```

Before, I did

```
 select * from transformServers(json)
```

which does not work.